# How to merge intervals based on a minimum gap of dates?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

My current table is like the below, each patient has their visit start date and end date to a hospital, and they are administered a drug between admin_startdate and admin_enddate. For example, the first two rows mean, patient PT1 has two drug administrations, one between 01/08 and 01/10 & the other between 01/12 and 01/23, during her visit from 01/01 to 01/31.

```
ptid    visit_start_date    visit_end_date  admin_startdate    admin_enddate
PT1       2018-01-01          2018-01-31        2018-01-08        2018-01-10
PT1       2018-01-01          2018-01-31        2018-01-12        2018-01-23
PT2       2018-01-02          2018-01-18        2018-01-06        2018-01-11
PT2       2018-01-02          2018-01-18        2018-01-14        2018-01-17
```

What I would like to achieve is to lump together the drug administration that are too close together, say, the end date of the previous one is `<= 2 days` of the start date of new one, and call that a whole episode, like below:

```
ptid    visit_start_date    visit_end_date  admin_startdate    admin_enddate  episode_startdate episode_enddate
PT1       2018-01-01          2018-01-31    2018-01-08        2018-01-10          2018-01-08         2018-01-23
PT1       2018-01-01          2018-01-31    2018-01-12        2018-01-23          2018-01-08         2018-01-23
PT2       2018-01-02          2018-01-18    2018-01-06        2018-01-11          2018-01-06         2018-01-11
PT2       2018-01-02          2018-01-18    2018-01-14        2018-01-17          2018-01-14         2018-01-17
```

You can see that PT1's two administrations are lumped together with the same `episode_startdate` and `episode_enddate`, whereas PT2's two administrations are considered two separate episode.

I have a hard time to figure out how to do it in PostgreSQL (Redshift).

Comment: Redshift is pretty distinct from Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This work in Postgres 14. Not tested for Redshift.

```sql
SELECT ptid, visit_start_date, visit_end_date, admin_startdate, admin_enddate
     , min(admin_startdate) OVER (PARTITION BY visit_id, admin) AS episode_startdate
     , max(admin_enddate)   OVER (PARTITION BY visit_id, admin) AS episode_enddate
FROM (
   SELECT *, count(*) FILTER (WHERE gap) OVER (PARTITION BY visit_id ORDER BY admin_startdate) AS admin
   FROM (
      SELECT *, admin_startdate - lag(admin_enddate) OVER (PARTITION BY visit_id ORDER BY admin_startdate) > 2 AS gap
      FROM  (
         SELECT *, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY ptid, visit_start_date, visit_end_date) AS visit_id  -- optional, to simplify
         FROM   tbl
         ) sub1
      ) sub2
   ) sub3
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=42cd5c54f47a4939030d826dbabd43e4)*

The innermost subquery `sub1` is only to compute a unique `visit_id` - which should really be in your table instead of repeating `(ptid, visit_start_date, visit_end_date )` over and over. Consider [normalizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your design at least that much.

The next subquery `sub2` checks for a gap that's greater than two days to the previous row in the same partition.

Subquery `sub3` then counts those gaps to identify distinct administration periods (`admin`)

In the outer `SELECT`, `min(admin_startdate)` and `max(admin_enddate)` per administration period produce the desired episode dates.

See (with assorted links to more):

- [How to group timestamps into islands (based on arbitrary gap)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55045788/how-to-group-timestamps-into-islands-based-on-arbitrary-gap/55065060#55065060)

Comment: @J.Z. If  the aggregate `FILTER` clause is the only incompatible bit, consider the added alternative: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ca3eb9056f67ee8919d94b5d6b096da2)* (Creating multiple aux. tables is ***much*** more expensive.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE TABLE tb1 AS (
SELECT *, admin_startdate - lag(admin_enddate) OVER (PARTITION BY visit_id ORDER BY admin_startdate) > 2 AS gap
      FROM  (
         SELECT *, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY ptid, visit_start_date, visit_end_date) AS visit_id  -- optional, to simplify
         FROM  tbl
) sub1
) ;

CREATE TABLE tb2 AS (
   SELECT *, count(*)  OVER (PARTITION BY visit_id ORDER BY admin_startdate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS admin
   FROM tb1
   WHERE gap is True
)
;

CREATE TABLE tb3 AS (
   SELECT tb1.ptid, tb1.visit_start_date, tb1.visit_end_date, tb1.admin_startdate, tb1.admin_enddate, tb1.visit_id, tb1.gap, 
   CASE WHEN tb2.admin is NULL THEN 0 else tb2.admin END AS admin
   FROM tb1 
   LEFT JOIN tb2
   ON tb1.ptid = tb2.ptid AND tb1.visit_start_date = tb2.visit_start_date AND tb1.visit_end_date = tb2.visit_end_date AND tb1.admin_startdate = tb2.admin_startdate AND tb1.admin_enddate = tb2.admin_enddate AND  tb1.visit_id = tb2.visit_id
)
;

CREATE TABLE tb4 AS (
   SELECT ptid, visit_start_date, visit_end_date, admin_startdate, admin_enddate
     , min(admin_startdate) OVER (PARTITION BY visit_id, admin) AS episode_startdate
     , max(admin_enddate)   OVER (PARTITION BY visit_id, admin) AS episode_enddate
     FROM tb3
)
```

This is an uglier version adapted from Erwin's answer for Redshift, which does not support FILTER operation. Tested correctly at least on [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=88ec4aafbcfb54e76f192ff6799d79ed)